# What does this symbol $∈_$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, cryptography

What does this symbol $∈_$ mean? I know what $x ∈ A$ stand for but what difference there is if we write $x ∈_R A$ ?

For those who wonder where did I encounter this symbol it was on one of a lecture slides on cryptography, pseudo random generators section. The excerpt said the following :

> For many cryptographic protocols, we need randomly chosen numbers $
> ∈_ ℤ_ = [0,−1]$.

Comment: Can you provide some context regarding where you encountered this?

Comment: Maybe that, it's real and also in A? Just a guess.

Comment: Perhaps $\in_R$ stands for the transitive closure of $\in$ (which should be read as "User Gae.S. knows two things, therefore it can only say one or the other"). But, well, the notation should be defined somewhere in the source you are reading.

Comment: Maybe it means $x$ is a randomly selected element of $A$?  But anyone using such a notation should explain it on first mention.

Comment: The thread has been edited to provide more useful information.

Comment: @Aqua I see now. The index R stands for randomly chosen. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cryptography literature usually $$x \in_{R} A,$$ stands for *randomly and uniformly chosen* from $A.$ If another distribution is implied $$x \in_{{\cal D}} A,$$ is used where $\cal D$ is a probability distribution on the set $A.$

Other authors prefer $$S \xleftarrow{R} x$$ or  $$S \xleftarrow{\cal D} x$$ especially when writing pseudocode for an algorithm.